# Failure [INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_UNEXPECTED_EXCEPTION] Android studio Error

Tags: android, android-studio

Every time I tried to run app on Emulator/Android Device from Android Studio.I get this error.  Any suggestions on how to proceed?

[image: dialog box]

[image: error]

Comment: Often you can get a more descriptive message if you try to install the APK from the command line using adb.  See https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/adb.html#move

Comment: Actually I am not trying to install/run from command line.I just press RUN button.And I get this error

Comment: I get that. My point is that when you install/run from Android Studio, the error dialog does not show you enough detail.  If you try to do your install from the command-line, just once, then the command-line utility, ADB, might give you a much more detailed error message that describes what is wrong.  This will enable you to fix the problem, after which you can return to installing from Android Studio.   This has worked for me.

Comment: ok, I will try that....

Comment: How to run an app in ADB?

Comment: [Please check this image](http://imgur.com/469oxcS)
I still got same error in command prompt